# jQuery multiple sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I fix the jQuery code below to have multiple sliders working correctly  using CSS class names (not IDs) ?

As you can see in the CodePen it's all over the place and not working as expected. The sliders are not working correctly.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ERGwRg)

HTML

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="slider-btn">
      <button class="slider-prev"><</button>
      <button class="slider-next">></button>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide active">
        <h2>Slide 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>Slide 2</h2>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div>
      <p>Some other content here</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="slider-btn">
      <button class="slider-prev"><</button>
      <button class="slider-next">></button>
    </div>      
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide active">
        <h2>Slide 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>Slide 2</h2>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div>
      <p>Some other content here</p> 
    </div>      
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

.active {
    transition: opacity 500ms ease;
    opacity:1;
}
```

JS

```
var allSlides = $('.slide');
var activeSlide = 0;

setInterval('autoSlide()', 4000);

$(".slider-next").click(function() {
  if (activeSlide+1 >= allSlides.length) {
    allSlides.eq(activeSlide).removeClass("active");
    activeSlide = 0;
    allSlides.eq(0).addClass("active");
  }
  else {
    allSlides.eq(activeSlide).removeClass("active");
    activeSlide++;
    allSlides.eq(activeSlide).addClass("active");
  }
});
$(".slider-prev").click(function() {
  if (activeSlide-1 < 0) {
    allSlides.eq(0).removeClass("active");
    activeSlide = allSlides.length-1;
    allSlides.eq(activeSlide).addClass("active");
  }
  else {
    allSlides.eq(activeSlide).removeClass("active");
    activeSlide--;
    allSlides.eq(activeSlide).addClass("active");
  }
});

function autoSlide() {
    if (activeSlide+1 >= allSlides.length) {
      allSlides.eq(activeSlide).removeClass("active");
      activeSlide = 0;
      allSlides.eq(0).addClass("active");
    }
    else {
      allSlides.eq(activeSlide).removeClass("active");
      activeSlide++;
      allSlides.eq(activeSlide).addClass("active");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unsure what you are doing with the sliders, but I was able to wire up the handlers and get you going. I set an array for the sliders, then at page load I wire up the handlers to the sliders. When the sliders are clicked, I think you want to loop through your index of sliders and set the css classes to active. I did that here. Be aware that the selection of the slider by index might be null. Tailor the answer to your use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link id="bs-css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link id="bsdp-css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .slider {
            position: relative;
            width: 80%;
        }

        .slide {
            position: relative;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .active {
            transition: opacity 500ms ease;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //set the array to the slide div's we have here
        var allSlides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");

        var activeSlide = 0;//start at 0

        setInterval('autoSlide()', 4000);
        $(function () { //when the document is ready, wire up the click functions
            $(".slider-next").click(function () {

                if (activeSlide + 1 >= allSlides.length) {
                    allSlides[activeSlide].className =""; //remove any css class on this item
                    activeSlide = 0;
                    allSlides[0].className["active"]; //careful, these items maybe null 
                }
                else {
                    allSlides[activeSlide].className="";
                    activeSlide++;
                    allSlides[activeSlide].className="active";
                }
            });
            $(".slider-prev").click(function () {
                if (activeSlide - 1 < 0) {
                    allSlides[0].className ="";
                    activeSlide = allSlides.length - 1;
                    allSlides[activeSlide].className= "active";
                }
                else {
                    allSlides[activeSlide].className= "";
                    activeSlide--;
                    allSlides[activeSlide].className ="active";
                }
            });
        });
        function autoSlide() {
            if (activeSlide + 1 >= allSlides.length) {
                allSlides[activeSlide].className = "";
                activeSlide = 0;
                allSlides[0].className ="active";
            }
            else {
                allSlides[activeSlide].className = ""; 
                activeSlide++;
                allSlides[activeSlide].className ="active";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="slider-btn">
            <button class="slider-prev"><</button>
            <button class="slider-next">></button>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide active">
                <h2>Slide 1</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h2>Slide 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Some other content here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-btn">
            <button class="slider-prev"><</button>
            <button class="slider-next">></button>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide active">
                <h2>Slide 1</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h2>Slide 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Some other content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks however this does not seem to work as it just brings up "Slide 2" randomly in each slider without hiding "Slide 1". The sliders should both only show one slide at a time with autoplay and the next/previous buttons which also don't seem to work and give console error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined".